# Sublime Text, open files depending on the git branch

Tags: git, sublimetext3

When I work, I always have 2 to 6/7/... branches where I edit usually completely different files. These branches usually don't exist for more than a few days, 2 or 3 weeks at most.

As I don't want to look for the files I modified or had opened last time I worked on one particular branch, I usually have as many ST opened as I have branches, and switch window each time I switch branches. It is still manageable, but I was wondering if anybody new of a package that would allow ST to track the branch I'm on, and restore the state it was in last time it was on this branch (I would settle for only opening the files that were opened, I don't really need to keep unsaved modifications).

Thank you for your time! I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: it might be a bit of an overkill, but if you add you project.sublime-workspace to version control (instead of keeping it in the ignore file), it will change each time you open or close a tab to keep the editor's state.   This means you'll also have to commit the changes before switching branches.

Comment: @amenadiel The only issue is ST does not seem to track the content of the project files to update in real time based on its content.
That means that even though I could possibly store what information I need, I would need manually load the project each time I switch branch. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to close the project, commit the workspace file, change branch, then open project. It's a lot of work and probably not a good solution :/

Comment: AFAIK there is currently no such functionality, not in ST core and not in any plugin I know of. But I guess it would be possible to write a plugin for this. It seems like a nice feature, I could imagine working on something like this.

Comment: Yep I think I'll start trying to put a plugin together...
I was hoping somebody would have already done it!

Comment: Did you make any progress on a plugin?

Comment: @Adamarla Actually I did. I just did not connect to stackoverflow in the past months... It comes as it is, there is no option whatsoever, the behavior may not always be the one you expect, but it worked well enough for me in the past months. Fair warning though, if you switch branch, this plugin will just erase all unsaved modifications/files. https://github.com/Xaelias/ST_Plugins/blob/master/BranchedWorkspace.py

Comment: Here's a plugin: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitOpenChangedFiles
It opens every file that's different from master, not just everything changed in the branch, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: @Qaz Thanks. I was really more interesting in something that would keep the files I had open, open. That way, even when working with files you don't modify, you can keep them as reference and everything. But indeed it's a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had forgotten about this post.
I actually did write a plugin for ST: https://github.com/Xaelias/ST_Plugins/blob/master/BranchedWorkspace.py

Like I said in the comment, there is no option, and the behavior may not be perfect for everybody, but it worked well enough for me (and I don't really had time to improve it).

Some comments:

- no option is available
- this WILL erase any unsaved modification/new file you created if you switch branch, no confirmation
- for the plugin to be aware of a branch, you need to leave it at least once while ST is running

If you have comments/questions/improvement, then Github is probably a better place but I will try to keep track of stuff happening here!